# GWAS MAC filter Interpretation

Tags: python, gwas

I am performing a GWAS analysis and try to understand the influence of the minor allele count filter.Setting the filter to 1 % gave me this plot and I am confused about the same -log10 pvalues around ~ 3.8 which shows a strange pattern (many dots in one line with same value).

[image]

If I increase the filter to 6 % the dots in a line disappear but I loose also some significant SNPs:

[image]

Sample are about 77000 SNP positions (barley), unimputed from GWAS (all NaNs removed). GWAS was performed with 200 phenotype samples.

How to interpret the dots in  a line?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Thanks. How many samples and what organism? I assume this is a snp chip?

Comment: Barley with 200 phenotypes.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the Manhattan plots: snps from different chromosomes are overlapping? For example, green does can be found inside the region for red dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like genotyping failed for some samples. It's unclear from the op whether the genotyping data was controlled for quality, but I would recommend performing sample QC.

On a side note: in human gwas with imputed snps, I would expect to see clusters of significant snps as a sign that the significant snps are not an artifact. In the op there are some single significant snps. This might be a sign that those significant snps are artifacts. There are also some snps that form clusters and therefore look more promising.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you very much for your answer. QC was not performed, going to do this now.

Comment: Follow up question:https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/14398/interpreting-gwas-results-with-different-settings